# ¿Cómo seleccionar el ítem de un combobox según su posición?

Tags: c#

Código:

```
int num = playerList.Items.Count;

for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
{

}
```

Ahora quiero que me seleccione en el `ComboBox` según la posición de `i` ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: Deberías aportar más código y dar más información de lo que quieres hacer para que se entienda la pregunta.

Comment: `ComboBox.SelectedIndex = i;` ¿No funciona?

Answer (score 1):

¿Como seleccionar un Item de un ComboBox según su posición? La posición es el : índice. La propiedad SelectedIndex de ComboBox puede devolver la posición seleccionada actualmente (get), así como puede ser establecida en otro índice (set), seleccionando otro elemento en base a su posición en el comboBox, empezando por 0 (1er Item del comboBox).

*Nota : cuando no hay un elemento seleccionado el valor de esta propiedad es null. El valor de esta propiedad es de tipo System.Int32*

```
// En adelante - 4 - o bien otra entrada para el valor del índice en que se
// vaya a establecer la posición del ComboBox.    

int comboBoxPositionIndex = 4;

playerList.SelectedIndex = comboBoxPositionIndex;
```

---

Si lo que quieres es que seleccione cada elemento del ComboBox según tu código, sería así :

```
    int num = playerList.Items.Count;

    // De momento, en este ejemplo, como el bucle solo tiene una linea, no son
    // necesarias las llaves.

    for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
        playerList.SelectedIndex = i;
```

*Nota : para que este segundo código haga algo realmente, debe añadirse algún otro código funcional en el cuerpo del bucle (poniendo todo entre llaves para el bucle), para que procese y aplique cada cambio, de otro modo es posible que no se aprecie el cambio de cada elemento, pues puede hacerlo demasiado rápido y no llegar a refrescar la ventana para cada item. Si por otro motivo queremos que fuerce el refresco para cada item, podemos añadir dentro del bucle :*

```
Application.DoEvents();
```